# Question about software versioning in Github as a total Git, Github and programming beginner

Tags: github, versioning

I started programming in Python recently as a beginner. I have a few little practice projects that are mostly from exercises in some books but I did from scratch (Yes, I'm planning my proper own projects in the near-future). Question is, should I version the software at all? They are just .py files for now.

I plan to create a small portfolio eventually, so I want to start with the best practices possible.
I just have the file names for now, such as "Restaurant1", "Restaurant2", etc.

Obviously there's no team associated to this, and I'm not "releasing" these programs, but mostly to learn best practices early on. So far, I have learned some basic git, such as initiating a repo, staging files to push them into the repo (git add, git push, pull, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git, making commits and pushing, then you already have a version history in git.

Type `git log` in your workspace to see that.

You do not need to version the file names.If you have got code in a state that you could call version 0.1 (or 1.0), then a git tag is useful for this.

You can type `git tag v0.1` and then `git push --tags`.

Alternatively, you could click the releases button in github, and draft a release. You can set this up to create a tag as it releases.